# generate random array where each entry can only belong to a discrete set of value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to generate a random matrix, with shape `(20, 30, 3)`. Each entry can only be either `255` or `0`. How to generate this kind of matrix using `numpy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use :

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

a: an array of possible values

size: output shape

p: probabilities associated with a

[source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice)

Thus, to solve our case with 50% probability for 0 and 255 each :

```
numpy.random.choice([0,255], size=(20,30,3), replace=True, p=[0.5,0.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency on a heads or tails approach :

```
a=255*np.random.randint(0,2,(20,30,3))
```